# Is it possible to control input processing time with scio JobTest?

Tags: spotify-scio

We are using com.spotify.scio.testing.JobTest for end to end testing of our scio pipeline. The pipeline includes a DoFn that is sensitive to data sequencing, on a stream of configuration data which arrives infrequently.

We are passing an ordered List of configuration values `combinedSampleConfig` as input to the JobTest Builder. Is there a way to have JobTest preserve the ordering of this CustomIO input stream when we run an end to end test?

I see that the testing framework enables fine control over source arrival time (using `advanceProcessingTime`) when testing individual components, but do not see how to apply this for end to end testing using JobTest.

```scala
    JobTest[MyApp.type]
      .args(commonArgs ++ Seq(
        "--numWorkers=1",
        "--maxNumWorkers=1",
      ): _*
      )
      .input(CustomIO[PubsubMessage](CONFIG_ID), combinedSampleConfig)
      .input(CustomIO[IndicatorEntry](INPUT_ID), sampleInput)
      .output(CustomIO[EnrichedIndicatorEntry](AGG_ID)) {
        _ should containInAnyOrder (expectedAggs)
      }
      .output(CustomIO[EnrichedIndicatorEntry](EVENT_ID)) {
        _ should containInAnyOrder (expectedEvents)
      }
      .run()
```

Comment: There isn't a way right now but probably doable by allowing Beam `TestStream` (which supports event timing) as input. I filed https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues/1891.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spotify/scio/pull/1905

This PR was recently merged and should allow such use case. Can you give it a try?